# Count unique Ips from access.log by day and minute

Tags: linux, apache, awk

I'm wondering if it is possible to count unique IPs by minute on a specific day (Apache access.log) on Ubuntu.

I already found this useful request which gives the requests per day/minute. But I unfortunatly dont make it to count the ips instead of the request lines:

```
grep "06/Sep/2021" access.log | cut -d[ -f2 | cut -d] -f1 |
awk -F: '{print $2":"$3}' | sort -nk1 -nk2 | uniq -c
```

My try is not that good:

```
grep "06/Sep/2021" access.log | awk '{print
substr($4,14,5)}' | sort | uniq | while read p; do   count=`grep $p
access.log | awk '{print $1}' | sort | uniq | wc
-l`   echo $count $p  done
```

Apache Access.log:

```
11.111.111.111 - - [06/Sep/2021:01:51:43 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 30783 "https://website.de/" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; website; +https://www.website.de/robot.html)" 2584 32146
    11.111.111.111 - - [06/Sep/2021:01:52:43 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 30783 "https://website.de/" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; website; +https://www.website.de/robot.html)" 2584 32146
    11.111.111.111 - - [06/Sep/2021:01:53:43 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 30783 "https://website.de/" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; website; +https://www.website.de/robot.html)" 2584 32146
    11.111.111.111 - - [06/Sep/2021:01:54:43 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 30783 "https://website.de/" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; website; +https://www.website.de/robot.html)" 2584 32146
    11.111.111.111 - - [06/Sep/2021:01:55:43 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 30783 "https://website.de/" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; website; +https://www.website.de/robot.html)" 2584 32146
    11.111.111.111 - - [06/Sep/2021:01:56:43 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 30783 "https://website.de/" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; website; +https://www.website.de/robot.html)" 2584 32146
    11.111.111.111 - - [06/Sep/2021:01:57:43 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 30783 "https://website.de/" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; website; +https://www.website.de/robot.html)" 2584 32146
    11.111.111.111 - - [06/Sep/2021:01:58:43 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 30783 "https://website.de/" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; website; +https://www.website.de/robot.html)" 2584 32146
    11.111.111.112 - - [06/Sep/2021:01:58:43 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 30783 "https://website.de/" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; website; +https://www.website.de/robot.html)" 2584 32146
    11.111.111.111 - - [06/Sep/2021:01:59:43 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 30783 "https://website.de/" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; website; +https://www.website.de/robot.html)" 2584 32146
    11.111.111.111 - - [06/Sep/2021:02:01:43 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 30783 "https://website.de/" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; website; +https://www.website.de/robot.html)" 2584 32146
    11.111.111.111 - - [06/Sep/2021:02:02:43 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 30783 "https://website.de/" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; website; +https://www.website.de/robot.html)" 2584 32146
    11.111.111.111 - - [06/Sep/2021:02:03:43 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 30783 "https://website.de/" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; website; +https://www.website.de/robot.html)" 2584 32146
    11.111.111.111 - - [06/Sep/2021:02:04:43 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 30783 "https://website.de/" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; website; +https://www.website.de/robot.html)" 2584 32146
    11.111.111.111 - - [06/Sep/2021:02:05:43 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 30783 "https://website.de/" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; website; +https://www.website.de/robot.html)" 2584 32146
    11.111.111.111 - - [06/Sep/2021:02:06:43 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 30783 "https://website.de/" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; website; +https://www.website.de/robot.html)" 2584 32146
    11.111.111.111 - - [06/Sep/2021:02:07:43 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 30783 "https://website.de/" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; website; +https://www.website.de/robot.html)" 2584 32146
    11.111.111.111 - - [06/Sep/2021:02:08:43 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 30783 "https://website.de/" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; website; +https://www.website.de/robot.html)" 2584 32146
    11.111.111.111 - - [06/Sep/2021:02:09:43 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 30783 "https://website.de/" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; website; +https://www.website.de/robot.html)" 2584 32146
    11.111.111.111 - - [06/Sep/2021:02:10:43 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 30783 "https://website.de/" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; website; +https://www.website.de/robot.html)" 2584 32146
    11.111.111.112 - - [06/Sep/2021:02:10:43 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 30783 "https://website.de/" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; website; +https://www.website.de/robot.html)" 2584 32146
```

Expected Output:

```
1 01:51
1 01:52
1 01:53
1 01:54
1 01:55
1 01:56
1 01:57
2 01:58
1 01:59
1 02:01
1 02:02
1 02:03
1 02:04
1 02:05
1 02:06
1 02:07
1 02:08
1 02:09
2 02:10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumptions:

- ip address does not matter; while there is mention of 'unique ip' in the title and body of the question, the expected output has no mention of ip addresses and the expected output counts do not appear to be segregated by ip

Adding a few lines with different dates:

```
$ cat access.log
11.111.111.111 - - [03/Sep/2021:01:51:43 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 30783 "https://website.de/" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; website; +https://www.website.de/robot.html)" 2584 32146
11.111.111.111 - - [01/Sep/2021:01:52:43 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 30783 "https://website.de/" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; website; +https://www.website.de/robot.html)" 2584 32146
... all of the lines from OP's sample input ...
11.111.111.112 - - [07/Sep/2021:02:10:43 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 30783 "https://website.de/" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; website; +https://www.website.de/robot.html)" 2584 32146
11.111.111.112 - - [10/Sep/2021:02:10:43 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 30783 "https://website.de/" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; website; +https://www.website.de/robot.html)" 2584 32146
```

One `awk` idea that replaces all of the `grep/awk/while/cut/sort/uniq` coding (and runs quite a bit faster to boot):

```
awk -v dt='06/Sep/2021' '
$0 ~ dt { split($0,timestamp,"[][]")
          split(timestamp[2],hrmin,":")
          count[hrmin[2]":"hrmin[3]]++
        }
END     { for (i in count) 
              print count[i],i
        }
' access.log | sort -k2V
```

This generates:

```
1 01:51
1 01:52
1 01:53
1 01:54
1 01:55
1 01:56
1 01:57
2 01:58    # ip addresses 11.111.111.11{1,2}
1 01:59
1 02:01
1 02:02
1 02:03
1 02:04
1 02:05
1 02:06
1 02:07
1 02:08
1 02:09
2 02:10    # ip addresses 11.111.111.11{1,2}
```

**NOTE:** if using `GNU awk` the `| sort -k2V` can be removed and the following change made to the `awk/END` block:

```
END     { PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_str_asc"
          for (i in count) 
              print count[i],i
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a `gnu-awk` solution to do this in a single command:

```sh
awk -v dt="06/Sep/2021" '
$0 ~ dt && gsub(/^[^:]+:|:[0-9]+$/, "", $4) { ++fq[$4] }
END {
   PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_str_asc"
   for (i in fq)
      print i, fq[i]
}' file.log

01:51 1
01:52 1
01:53 1
01:54 1
01:55 1
01:56 1
01:57 1
01:58 2
01:59 1
02:01 1
02:02 1
02:03 1
02:04 1
02:05 1
02:06 1
02:07 1
02:08 1
02:09 1
02:10 2
```

`PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_str_asc"` has been used to sorting keys in ascending string order.

Comment: This worked perfect! This there a chance that we do not use any logfile and just print it in the terminal?

Comment: Above command prints it on stdout or terminal only.

Answer (score 1):

With your shown samples, please try following `awk` program.

```
awk -v dt="06/Sep/2021" '
$0 ~ dt && match($0,/\[[^ ]*/){
  arr[substr($0,RSTART+13,RLENGTH-16)]++
}
END{
  for(key in arr){
    print key,arr[key]
  }
}
'  Input_file | sort -k1
```

***Explanation:*** Using `awk` program and parsing Input_file from it. Making `awk` variable named `dt` which has value as `06/Sep/2021`. In Main program checking if line contains dt variable AND using `match` function to match regex from `[` till space(which will basically get `[06/Sep/2021:02:01:43`). Creating arr array which has index as matched  regex value in it. In `END` block of `awk` program traversing through elements of `arr` and printing key and its value. Sending its output to sort to get output in sorted form.